# Accessing mounted S3 on ubuntu using s3fs - using apache

Tags: apache, amazon-s3, http-status-code-403, s3fs

I have mounted s3 bucket on ubuntu using s3fs. All i need to do is access this bucket (which has got my media files) using apache. I did set `DocumentRoot` on `/etc/apache2/sites-available` to S3 path, but when i access `http://ubuntu_domain_name:80/BUCKET` it says 403. I did made bucket in S3 still it says 403.  ( where ubuntu is an EC2 instance).

Then i pointed document root to some other directory, and created symbolic links to bucket, still i see 403 error.

All i want is, access S3 bucket with media files through apache sitting on ubuntu ec2.

Can anybody point me where i am doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: When you mount the filesystem you'll need to make sure it gets mounted such that the user apache is running as can read the files. It's probably being mounted with more restrictive permissions than that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Any help of mount is appreciated, I used this command, `s3fs -o password_file=<path_pwd_file> BUCKETNAME /mnt/MOUNTPOINT` , is there any other way to mount ?

Comment: Assuming it's just a standard fuse filesystem adding `allow_other` into your list of options should be sufficient

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Looks like i found the answer. This is what i have done,                                                                `s3fs BUCKETNAME  -o allow_other -o password_file=<path_pwd_file> /mnt/mountpoint `                                                     and in apache, i gave `/mnt/mountpoint` as document root.

Answer (score 2):

It can be handy to set a default acl when mounting the bucket...

```
/usr/bin/s3fs my-bucket /mnt/my-bucket -odefault_acl=public-read
```

Important when configuring fstab as well....

I wrote a blog on it at [thecodeabode: s3fs and ubuntu](http://thecodeabode.blogspot.com.au/2012/11/s3fs-mounting-s3-on-ec2-instance.html)

Answer (score -2):

You can also specify a uid and gid in the s3 connection string  ie

;uid=5